# How i can know the email addresses which have received a user notification email when an item is added to a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, administration, logs

We have sharepoint online tenant, and some users have set user alerts on a discussion board list, to receive emails when anything is changed. But some users are reporting that they are not receiving alerts, although i asked them to send me a screen shot of the user alert settings, and looks like everything is set correct.

so i am not sure if i can check the email addresses which received the user notification emails ? Previously inside the on-premises i used to check the sharepoint logs, which will specify the email addresses to whome the email were sent to .. but not sure if this is possible inside sharepoint online?
Thanks

Comment: You cannot check SharePoint online log unless you contact MS support team .

Comment: @AnthonyWangMSFT Thanks for the reply. so in this case if a user reported that he did not receive an alert email, then we need to contact MS?? and i can not check this from our office 365 reports?